# Efficiently concatenating large serially produced arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, three.js, concatenation

I am combining many long arrays (80 arrays of 80,000 elements each, eventually more) into several single arrays (8 arrays of 1,600,000 elements each) to be uploaded as attributes in a Three.js BufferGeometry. I struggled to get the process efficient enough not to freeze the browser. I'm past that point, but it is still painfully slow. Is there any approach that might speed this up - optimizations I should consider? I tried using `push.apply`, which sped the process considerably, but eventually exceeded the call stack. I'm currently working with `concat`, but wonder if converting the process to strings or another data structure, and then back again might help? Other ideas? I'm all ears.

Here are the code blocks in question:

```
var motifMinBufferSize = 80000;

function setMinimumBufferSize( pointCloudAttributeArray, itemSize, fillValue ) {
    // buffers cannot be resized once they've been sent to the graphics card, so I am emulating resizing by setting a minimum buffer size that exceeds the number of vertex positions in the largest known point cloud.
    supplementalArray.fill( fillValue );
    var fullArray = pointCloudAttributeArray.concat( supplementalArray );
    return fullArray;
}


function flattenVertexArray( array ) {
    var flattenedArray = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        flattenedArray.push( array[i].x, array[i].y, array[i].z );
    }
    return flattenedArray;
}


function concatArrays( gridArray, motifArray ) {
    var newGridArray = [];
    newGridArray = gridArray.concat( motifArray );
    return newGridArray;
}


function compileGridOfPointCloudAttributes( ... ) {

    ...code to compile the attributes for a BufferGeometry representing a grid of point clouds...
    // Skipping ahead in the function:
    for ( var i = 0; i < 80; i++ ) {
        ...
        // I have 8 of these attributes that gradually accumulate representing 80,000 values each for 80 different particle clouds:
            var position = flattenVertexArray( motif.position );
            var aGridPosition = flattenVertexArray ( motif.aGridPosition );

            pointCloudGridAttributes.aPointCloudIDPerVertex = concatArrays( pointCloudGridAttributes.aMotifIDPerVertex, setMinimumBufferSize( motif.aPointCloudIDPerVertex, 1, 0 ) );
            pointCloudGridAttributes.position = concatArrays( pointCloudGridAttributes.position, setMinimumBufferSize( position, 3, gridDimensions.gridWidth ) );
            pointCloudGridAttributes.aGridPosition = concatArrays( pointCloudAttributes.aGridPosition, setMinimumBufferSize( motif.aGridPosition, 1, 0 ) );
        ...continue like this for 5 more attributes...
    }
}
```

**Context:**
I'm making a visualization with Three.js composed of 80 or so particle clouds, each with a unique number of points (50,000+ points per cloud) and all composed into a single `BufferGeometry` for efficient rendering. I periodically swap out on point cloud for another, but learned that the buffers in a buffer geometry are not resizable once they are implemented, so I now have a a fixed, oversized section of the array dedicated to each point cloud.

Comment: Do not create temporary javascript arrays. See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_points.html